# How to run MongoDB $Merge from command line (how to specify source?)

Tags: mongodb

This [MongDB Merge Doc page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#comparison-with-out) shows the following example:

```
{ $merge: { into: "myOutput", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }
```

Can I run this from the command line?  Do I have to put something in front of it?  I see "myOutput" is the target collection name.  How do I specify the "from" collection name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$merge` is an aggregate stage, so you can just aggregate the collection you wish to merge from.

To simply merge two collection by id shell would be:

```
db.FROMCOLLECTION.aggregate([{ $merge: { into: "myOutput", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }])
```

You can also make changes to existing docs with other stages and/or only merge some docs by adding a `$match` stage.

```
db.FROMCOLLECTION.aggregate([{$match: {someField: 'match this'}}, { $merge: { into: "myOutput", on: "_id", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }])
```